# R Test Condition For Many Rows

Tags: r, loops

```
d=data.frame("STUDENT"=c(1,2,3,4),
             "SCORE1"=c(64,68,65,65),
             "SCORE2"=c(91,78,94,55),
             "SCORE3"=c(84,62,73,61),
             'IMPROVE'=c('T','T','T','F'))

d$IMPROVE1 = ifelse(d[d$STUDENT==1,d$SCORE1] < d[d$STUDENT==1,d$SCORE2] | d[d$STUDENT==1,d$SCORE3], T, F)
```

I aim to create IMPROVE which is different for each STUDENT. It equals to T if STUDENT has SCORE2 or SCORE3  greater than SCORE1. It equals to F if STUDENT does not have SCORE2 or SCORE3 greater than SCORE1. I give my sample data and attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
d$IMPROVE1 <- FALSE
d$IMPROVE1[d$SCORE1 < d$SCORE2 | d$SCORE1 < d$SCORE3] <- TRUE
d
>  STUDENT SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 IMPROVE IMPROVE1
1       1     64     91     84       T     TRUE
2       2     68     78     62       T     TRUE
3       3     65     94     73       T     TRUE
4       4     65     55     61       F    FALSE
```

For any number of score :

```
scores <- grep("SCORE", colnames(d), value = TRUE)[-1]
sapply(1:nrow(d), function(s) any(d$SCORE1[s] < d[s,scores]))
```

For known columns of score as requested in comments:

```
column_scores <- 3:4
column_ref <- 2
sapply(1:nrow(d), function(s) any(d[s, column_ref] < d[s, column_scores]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of a logical expression doesn't need any changes

```
d$IMPOROVE1 <- with(d, (SCORE1 < SCORE2) | (SCORE1 < SCORE3))
d$IMPROVE1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Also, for multiple columns a vectorized approach would be create the logical vector with `rowSums`  from the logical `matrix` created by comparing single column with multiple other 'SCORE' columns

```
rowSums(d$SCORE1 < d[grep("SCORE", names(d))][-1]) > 0
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
d$IMPROVE1 = ifelse(d$SCORE1 < d$SCORE2 |d$SCORE1 < d$SCORE3, T, F)
```

Comment: This nice @Cettt suppose I had 10 tests can I code this effectively by using [,] instead of col name?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know what you mean by "using [.] instead".

Comment: So this way I do not want to have to name SCORE1, SCORE2, SCORE3, SCORE4 and so and and so forth if I have to check for improvement on 10 SCORES. So by [,] I mean if use the position instead of the name for example 1:10 instead of SCORE1 to SCORE10.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to know if the first score is worse than all next scores ?

Comment: Yes but there are 10+ so not to write SCORE each time so basically compare SCORE1 for STUDENT1 to all OTHER SCORES for STUDENT1 and do this for all STUDENTS. Cheers!

Comment: @Clemsang thank you it is indeed helpful however sometimes these things may have data entry error in spelling so preferable would be to avoid spelling and to use the positions instead of the column names if that is option. Simply put I did not know how to incorporate this remark for my question and if it makes sense still.